# Slide Show in react

Tags: reactjs

I have code written in pure js. Now I want to put that code in my reactJS component, but there are bugs, can you help me resolve?
here is Slide in pure js

```
    var imgArray = [
        'http://placehold.it/300x200',
        'http://placehold.it/200x100',
        'http://placehold.it/400x300'],
        curIndex = 0;
        imgDuration = 1000;

    function slideShow() {
        document.getElementById('slider').className += "fadeOut";
        setTimeout(function() {
            document.getElementById('slider').src = imgArray[curIndex];
            document.getElementById('slider').className = "";
        },1000);
        curIndex++;
        if (curIndex == imgArray.length) { curIndex = 0; }
        setTimeout(slideShow, imgDuration);
    }
    slideShow();
```

```
<img id="slider" src="http://placehold.it/50x200">
```

```
    #slider {
        opacity:1;
        transition: opacity 1s; 
    }

    #slider.fadeOut {
        opacity:0;
    }
```

I write something like that but it not working 
https://c02iz.csb.app/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question does not follow the good question approach. Please have a look at this link - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more info on how to ask good questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is correct code. You can check [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-chatterjee-qxr5x?file=/src/App.js:0-712)

and you can use any react plugin for slider like [react-slick](https://react-slick.neostack.com/)

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const imgArray = ["./1.png", "./2.png"];
  let curIndex = 0;
  let imgDuration = 3000;

  function slideShow() {
    if (document.getElementById("slider")) {
      document.getElementById("slider").className += "fadeOut";
      setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById("slider").src = imgArray[curIndex];
        document.getElementById("slider").className = "";
      }, 1000);
    }
    curIndex++;
    if (curIndex === imgArray.length) {
      curIndex = 0;
    }
    setTimeout(slideShow, imgDuration);
  }
  slideShow();
  return (
    <div>
      <img id="slider" alt="" src="./3.png" />
    </div>
  );
}
```